# Android Studio SQLite Insert Data

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, mobile

I am creating a database and then trying to select some data from it. Below is my DBHelper file which successfully creates the database and tries to insert data into it:

```
 package com.racecoursedatatechnologies.rdtstockmanagement;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Version number
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

//Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "rdt.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //All tables are created here
    String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbTables.userTABLE + "("
            + dbTables.uID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + dbTables.username + " TEXT, "
            + dbTables.userpassword + " TEXT );";

    String CREATE_TABLE_STOCK = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbTables.stockTABLE + "("
            + dbTables.sID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
            + dbTables.itemname + " TEXT, "
            + dbTables.itemdescription + " TEXT, "
            + dbTables.itemamount + " INTEGER, "
            + dbTables.itemimage + " TEXT );";

    //Create tables using execute function
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STOCK);

    //Now add our first user automatically which is the administrator.
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(dbTables.username, "Administrator");
    contentValues.put(dbTables.userpassword, "abc123");
    db.insert(dbTables.userTABLE, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbTables.userTABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbTables.stockTABLE);

    //Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}



 }
```

I am then trying to select the uID column that I have inserted into the database table to see if the user exists with the name and password and can login using the following code:

```
//Attempt the user login
public void attemptLogin(View v)
{

    EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    String input_name = et1.getText().toString();
    String input_password = et2.getText().toString();
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

  String selectQuery = "SELECT " +
            dbTables.uID +
            " FROM " + dbTables.userTABLE +
            " WHERE " + dbTables.username +
            " = " + "'" + input_name + "'" + " AND " +
            dbTables.userpassword + " = " + "'" + input_password + "'";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){

        Integer userID = c.getInt(0);

        Log.d("DATABASE", userID.toString());

    }

    c.close();
    db.close();
```

However the application keeps crashing out when I press the button saying it cannot find the Column 'Administrator' but I am inserting the data upon creating the database??

Comment: try String column1 = c.getString(1); because field at 0th index is ID and field at 1st index is username

Comment: Hi I am trying to just print the user ID at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround string values with `''` or the database thinks your value is a command.

String selectQuery = `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='" + input_name + "'";`

Comment: Thanks it has solved the crash but the Log.d doesn't print the user ID im trying to get!

Comment: Try to execute: if(c.moveToFirst()){

        String column1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbTables.username));

        Log.d("DATABASE", column1);
    }

Comment: Your code throws an error saying cannot convert Long to String, but just to let you know if have updated the main code above.

Comment: Just identified an error on my previous comment, please update.

Comment: Doesn't print anything

Comment: Just to let you know I am only trying to select the userID from the select query now. It doesn't seem to get past the moveToFirst()

Comment: `if (c.moveToFirst()) {
 do {
  Log.d("DATABASE", "Found a Value");
  int column1 = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(dbTables.userID)); Log.d("DATABASE", String.valueOf(column1));
  
 } while (c.moveToNext());
}`

Strange, this should work. Verify your input, with first letter captalize in 'Administrator'.

Answer (score 1):

**Rectify your Query**

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE  username"+ " = '"+ input_name  +"'";
```

**FYI**

*Convert Integer to String*

```
Log.d("DATABASE", String.valueOf(userID));
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the crash but the Log.d doesnt print the user ID im trying to get

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci if your code perfect then properly convert `Integer ` to `String` the use `Log.D`

Comment: `Log.d("DATABASE", String.valueOf(userID));`